# Website's file types all set as HTML when going through HaProxy

Tags: iis, haproxy, devops

When I open "my-website.com", the full page never loads because the .css and .js files seem to be served as html. This only happens when accessing the website through my loadbalencer.

I have a website hosted on a IIS server (Windows Server 2008R2). The MIME types seem to be correctly defined by default by IIS, .css points to text/css and .js points to application/x-javascript.

When I open the website through it's IP directly (https://host_ip/loginpage) all the files load correctly.
When I open the website through loadbalancer (my-website.com in our dns points to haproxy server than then sends it to the IIS server on port 443), the page doesn't seem to load fully and when I check my browser tools, I see that all the files say "type html". I also have a few errors like:

The stylesheet https://my-website.com/loginpage/Scripts/css/stylesfile.css?cdv=20242058 was not loaded because it's MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

Is this happening because the files technically don't end in .css (but .css?cdv=some_numbers), thus it's ignoring the IIS MIME type rules? If so, why doesn't that happen when accessing the website directly?

Here's a bit of my haproxy configuration:

```
frontend fe_my-website.com
        mode http
        bind :443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/my-cert.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
        bind :80
        redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

        stick-table type ip size 5k expire 10h
        stick on src
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix

        # HSTS (63072000 seconds)
        http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=63072000

        # ACLs for my-website.com
        acl acl_my-website hdr(host) -i my-website.com
        use_backend be_my-website if acl_my-website



# backends
backend be_my-website
        mode http
        option httpchk
        http-request set-path /loginpage
        server my-website.com host_ip:443 check ssl verify none
```

I'm not the website developer, I'm just the devops, so I'd like to try to solve this on the haproxy side, if it can be solved that way. Regardless, if you think of any possible solution I appreciate it. Am I doing something wrong on the load balencer or do I just have to tell the dev to add style="text/css" and similar to his pages?

---

EDIT: So apparently the problem was in the directive "http-request set-path /loginpage". When I do this, haproxy removes the rest of the information from the header and then the files are set as text/html. However, I can't find a way to send the request to a specific path without losing the headers information. So, right now my problem is that I can't redirect the user from "my-website.com" to "my-website.com/loginpage" from the haproxy, without breaking the website.